# PDF attachment open in browser on Mac Email application

Tags: php, macos, email, email-attachments, email-client

I'm sending email with a PDF attachment through PHP. It works fine on every webmail, Thunderbird, Outlook, iOs, but on Mac OS X Mail application I have a weird behaviour: when I click on the PDF attachment, it open the website home page from where I sent the email in browser. Though if I right click on the attachment and choose to open in Acrobat PDF it works fine. Other emails with PDF attachment are opening as expected, so it's related to some mail header and not the software configuration.

[A known issue](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5258265?tstart=0) is that PDF open in browser instead of Acrobat PDF, which would not be such a problem if it wouldn't redirect to homepage.

Here is the relevant parts of the email source:

```
To: me@example.com
Subject: My email
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 10006:mail.inc.php
From: them@example.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Mailer: Html Mime Mail Class
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
    boundary="=_02f1bb81e24e79ba7b9a88259d584c02"
Reply-to: them@example.com

This is a MIME encoded message.

--=_02f1bb81e24e79ba7b9a88259d584c02
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="=_9bb751c17df5df4380796b97e7544792"

--=_9bb751c17df5df4380796b97e7544792
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

No text version was provided

--=_9bb751c17df5df4380796b97e7544792
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

[... html content ...]

--=_9bb751c17df5df4380796b97e7544792--

--=_02f1bb81e24e79ba7b9a88259d584c02
Content-Type: application/pdf;
    name="my_pdf_file.pdf"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="my_pdf_file.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

[... attachment in base 64 ...]
```

So `Content-Type` and `Content-Disposition` are correctly set, but it seems Apple Mail ignore the `Content-Disposition`. Is there some others headers that I could set to force the attachment download?

Not sure if it's relevant to the problem, but I'm using [this mail class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/32-PHP-A-class-for-sending-mime-email-.html#view_files/files/90) (HTML Mime Mail) with the following setup:

```
require_once("../../lib/HTMLMimeMail/mail.inc.php");
ob_start();
include('../../app/View/Email/myemail.php');
$bodyHtml = ob_get_contents();
ob_clean();

$subject = 'My email';
$_envoiMail = new html_mime_mail("X-Mailer: Html Mime Mail Class");
$_envoiMail->set_charset('utf-8');
$_envoiMail->add_html($bodyHtml, '');
$file_name = '../../../../uploads/my_pdf_file.pdf';
$attachment = $_envoiMail->get_file(dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . $file_name);
$_envoiMail->add_attachment($attachment, 'my_pdf_file.pdf', 'application/pdf');
$_envoiMail->build_message();
$_envoiMail->send('Me', 'me@example.com', 'Them', 'them@example.com', $subject, "Reply-to: them@example.com");
```